# Python/Pandas - Como criar no data frame, uma coluna "str" a partir de outra numérica, incluindo zero à esquerda quando o valor for menor que 9

Tags: python, pandas

O código que utilizei para criar a coluna está retornando com o seguinte erro:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
>   a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Não sei como resolver este erro.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
raw_data = {'regiment': ['Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks'],
            'company': ['1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd'],
            'deaths': ['kkk', 52, '25', 616],
            'battles': [5, 42, 2, 2],
            'size': ['l', 'll', 'l', 'm']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['regiment', 'company', 'deaths', 'battles', 'size'])

def valida_CEP(x):
    if x < 9:
        return '0' + str(x)
    else:
        return str(x)

df['batles_comzero'] = df.apply(valida_CEP(df['battles']),axis=1)

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Estou usando u jupyter notebook e o seu exemplo retornou o seguinte erro:
C:\Users\Antonio\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy from ipykernel import kernelapp as app No link indicado não entendi como resolver este problema.

Comment: Tente usar a expressão seguinte: df['batles_comzero'] = df.battles.apply(valida_CEP)

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma rápida de fazer isso ([TL;DR](https://repl.it/JHW6)):

**Criando a nova coluna:**

```
df['com_zeros'] = '0'
```

**Aplicando a condição::**

```
for b in df.itertuples():
    df.com_zeros[b.Index] = '0'+str(b.battles) if b.battles<9 else str(b.battles)
```

**Resultado:**

```
df
     regiment company deaths  battles size com_zeros
0  Nighthawks     1st    kkk        5    l        05
1  Nighthawks     1st     52       42   ll        42
2  Nighthawks     2nd     25        2    l        02
3  Nighthawks     2nd    616        2    m        02
```

[Veja o exemplo rodando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/JHW6)

**Obs.:**
O exemplo [rodando no repl.it](https://repl.it/JHW6) parece que trava, mas não é o caso, a carga do pandas no repl.it, é sempre demorada.

Para suprimir warnings em jupyter notebook:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```